# How can I create a SQL query that looks at the time interval between two consecutive records

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

How can I reference the previous and next row in a query, as well as the current?

I have a table to record car journeys from A to B. the structure is similar to this…

```
CREATE TABLE journeys (
  journeyID       SERIAL,
  vehicleId       CHAR(15),               
  startTime       TIMESTAMP,              
  endTime         TIMESTAMP               
);
```

Each row represents a single journey, how can I find the turn-around time between one journey ending and the next journey starting?

For each journey I want to be able to refer to the previous row (when sorted chronologically) to establish CURR.startTime – PREV.endTime. Note – journeyId is not sequential and is not in chronological order.

I’ve tried a self-join onto a duplicate of the same table, but because I can’t uniquely identify the subsequent journey I end up with a product-query that returns a massive set of results.

(I'm working with PostGres, but would prefer an ANSI SQL solution if possible)

Addendum for Aaron - I'm trying to get the time interval between two records, If a have one journey for a given vehicleID that ends at 12 noon (endTime) and the subsequent journey (for the same vehicle) starts at 12:45 (startTime), then the time interval between the two would be 45 minutes.

Comment: The answer is almost definitely going to be `LAG()`, but it's a little unclear what you want.  Could you provide sample data and expected output for a journey or two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use `LAG()` to access the previous row's `endTime`.  `LAG()` and similar window functions are available in most DBMS (will be coming to MySQL 8.0).

Your query will look something like this:

```
SELECT journeyID, vehicleID, startTime, endTime, 
       startTime - LAG(endTime) over (PARTITION BY vehicleID ORDER BY startTime ASC) as timeBetweenJourneys
FROM journeys
```